# Error in C++ due to # define MAX

Tags: c++

I was just developing a simple stack program in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#define MAX 3;
using namespace std;

class stack
{
private:
    int arr[3];
    int top;

public:
    stack()
    {
        top=-1;
    }
    void push(int item)
    {
        if(top==MAX-1)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"STACK FULL";
            return;
        }
        top++;
        arr[top]=item;
        cout<<endl<<"Pushed "<<item;
    }
    int pop()
    {
        if(top==-1)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"STACK EMPTY";
            return NULL;
        }
        int temp=arr[top];
        top--;
        return temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);

    cout<<endl<<"Popped "<<s.pop();
    cout<<endl<<"Popped "<<s.pop();
    cout<<endl<<"Popped "<<s.pop();
    cout<<endl<<"Popped "<<s.pop();
}
```

and I got this as a gift

```
naveen@linuxmint ~/Desktop/C++ $ g++ stack.cpp -o stack
stack.cpp: In member function ‘void stack::push(int)’:
stack.cpp:18:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
stack.cpp:18:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
stack.cpp: In member function ‘int stack::pop()’:
stack.cpp:32:11: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
```

When I remove `# define MAX 3` and `return NULL` I get no error .Why is it giving errors?

Comment: This being C++, you may want to replace `#define MAX 3;` by `static const int MAX = 3;`.

Comment: It's really easy to have a macro name collision with something like `MAX`. I'd recommend avoiding macros at all by using something like `static const size_t MaxStackSize = 3;`.

Comment: Secondly ,Why I get a warning due to NULL?

Comment: @Insane, that's because you're returning `NULL` from a method that's supposed to return an `int`.

Answer (score 19):

Remove the `;` from your `define MAX 3 ;` line. That will expand to something like

```
if(top==3 ;-1)
```

which is definitely not what you want. Remember that `#define` is a preprocessor directive, not a C statement.

A probably even better idea would be to change it to a constant rather than a `#define` using something like

```
static const unsigned MAX = 3;
```

which avoids all the preprocessor entirely.

Answer (score 12):

It is not a good idea to define constants in `#define`.

Change `#define MAX 3;` to `#define MAX 3`

A related article for this:- [Do not conclude macro definitions with a semicolon](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE11-C.+Do+not+conclude+macro+definitions+with+a+semicolon)

An alternative could be:-

```
static const unsigned MAX = 3;
```

Comment: Using #define for constants is a bad idea since it ignores scope

Comment: And also the `type safety`

Comment: @UchiaItachi:- Yes I agree!!! :)